# How to add underline to selected side menu item in SlidingMenu?

Tags: android, listview, slidingmenu

I want to put an underline to my selected side menu item.Is there any way to put only an underline to the item name instead of highlighting the whole item?

Comment: I think making a custom selector and apply it to that item will help you.

Comment: can u help me with that please ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <item android:drawable="your drawable when pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="your drawable when selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="your drawable when activated" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

The above code is a simple selector from where you can make the one that you need and you also need to add `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` to your listview and also add the selector `listView.setSelector(R.drawable.your_selector);` or you can add in xml like `android:listSelector="@drawable/your_selector"`

A better selector for your need would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="3dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: thanks for your answer.this is working but it doesn't stay.It just blinks and disappears.i did just like what u said.

Comment: if you used the seccond example then you would need to also add the other states that can be seen in the first example and also you can try to add `view.setSelected(true);` in `onItemClickListener`

Comment: I used first example.

Comment: Could u please help me fix this?